# Android Eclipse Crashlytics Plugin Beta Window Doesn't Display

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

I am building my Android application on Mac with eclipse v4.2.1 and Android Development Toolkit v23.0 and distributing to beta testers through Crashlytics plugin v1.7.0.

Recently, the Crashlytics plugin would occasionally refuse to popup after pressing the Crashlytics toolbar button. Often, it would work once, but not again in the same eclipse session requiring an eclipse restart.

Now, the Crashlytics popup never displays. I can tell that it thinks it is visible because of the hover tooltip and the grayed out status of the eclipse window decorations.

Additionally, trying to display the plugin via this method fails:
Window > Show View > Other... > Crashlytics > Crashlytics Plugin Admin View

I have checked for plugin updates, but the current version v1.7.0 won't install because eclipse reports that the plugin is already up to date.

- **How to fix the Crashlytics plugin?** Or,
- **How to upload stand-alone as in the suggested Ant/Mavin methods?**